Pymoo install fail
When trying to pip install pymoo I get the failure warning below.Tried updating pip but that did not solve the problem. Looks like there is an issue with the egg but have no clue as to how to begin resolving it. C:\Program Files\Spyder\Python\Scripts> is added to PATH.
Any suggestions on how to get pymoo installed successfully?
C:\Program Files\Spyder\Python\Scripts>pip install -U pymoo
Collecting pymoo
  Using cached pymoo-0.6.1.2.tar.gz (1.3 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\AvdKAdmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7pe_9kfn\pymoo_b3604a5d5c0444c584d6f0acf707f036\setup.py", line 11, in <module>
          from pymoo.version import __version__
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymoo'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

C:\Program Files\Spyder\Python\Scripts>

My installed packages:
C:\Program Files\Spyder\Python\Scripts>pip list
Package                       Version
----------------------------- --------------
alabaster                     0.7.13
arrow                         1.3.0
astroid                       3.2.2
asttokens                     2.4.1
atomicwrites                  1.4.1
attrs                         23.2.0
autopep8                      2.0.4
Babel                         2.15.0
backcall                      0.2.0
backports.tarfile             1.2.0
beautifulsoup4                4.12.3
binaryornot                   0.4.4
black                         24.4.2
bleach                        6.1.0
blinker                       1.8.2
certifi                       2024.6.2
cffi                          1.16.0
chardet                       5.2.0
charset-normalizer            3.3.2
click                         8.1.7
cloudpickle                   3.0.0
colorama                      0.4.6
comm                          0.2.2
contourpy                     1.1.1
cookiecutter                  2.6.0
cryptography                  42.0.8
cycler                        0.12.1
Cython                        3.0.10
debugpy                       1.8.1
decorator                     5.1.1
defusedxml                    0.7.1
diff-match-patch              20230430
dill                          0.3.8
docstring-to-markdown         0.15
docutils                      0.20.1
et-xmlfile                    1.1.0
executing                     2.0.1
ez_setup                      0.9
fastjsonschema                2.19.1
flake8                        7.0.0
Flask                         3.0.3
Flask-MySQLdb                 2.0.0
fonttools                     4.53.0
idna                          3.7
imagesize                     1.4.1
importlib_metadata            7.1.0
importlib_resources           6.4.0
inflection                    0.5.1
intervaltree                  3.1.0
ipykernel                     6.29.4
ipython                       8.12.3
isort                         5.13.2
itsdangerous                  2.2.0
jaraco.classes                3.4.0
jaraco.context                5.3.0
jaraco.functools              4.0.1
jedi                          0.19.1
jellyfish                     1.0.4
Jinja2                        3.1.4
jsonschema                    4.22.0
jsonschema-specifications     2023.12.1
jupyter_client                8.6.2
jupyter_core                  5.7.2
jupyterlab_pygments           0.3.0
keyring                       25.2.1
kiwisolver                    1.4.5
markdown-it-py                3.0.0
MarkupSafe                    2.1.5
matplotlib                    3.7.5
matplotlib-inline             0.1.7
mccabe                        0.7.0
mdurl                         0.1.2
mistune                       3.0.2
more-itertools                10.3.0
mpmath                        1.3.0
mypy-extensions               1.0.0
mysqlclient                   2.2.4
nbclient                      0.10.0
nbconvert                     7.16.4
nbformat                      5.10.4
nest-asyncio                  1.6.0
networkx                      3.1
numpy                         1.24.4
numpydoc                      1.7.0
openpyxl                      3.1.3
packaging                     24.1
pandas                        2.0.3
pandocfilters                 1.5.1
paramiko                      3.4.0
parso                         0.8.4
pathspec                      0.12.1
pexpect                       4.9.0
pickleshare                   0.7.5
pillow                        10.3.0
pip                           24.2
pkgutil_resolve_name          1.3.10
platformdirs                  4.2.2
pluggy                        1.5.0
prompt_toolkit                3.0.47
psutil                        6.0.0
ptyprocess                    0.7.0
pure-eval                     0.2.2
pycodestyle                   2.11.1
pycparser                     2.22
pydocstyle                    6.3.0
pyflakes                      3.2.0
Pygments                      2.18.0
pylint                        3.2.3
pylint-venv                   3.0.3
pyls-spyder                   0.4.0
pyparsing                     3.1.2
PyQt5                         5.15.10
PyQt5-Qt5                     5.15.2
PyQt5-sip                     12.13.0
PyQtWebEngine                 5.15.6
PyQtWebEngine-Qt5             5.15.2
python-dateutil               2.9.0.post0
python-lsp-black              2.0.0
python-lsp-jsonrpc            1.1.2
python-lsp-server             1.11.0
pytoolconfig                  1.3.1
pytz                          2024.1
pywin32                       306
pywin32-ctypes                0.2.2
pyxdg                         0.28
PyYAML                        6.0.1
pyzmq                         26.0.3
QDarkStyle                    3.2.3
qstylizer                     0.2.3
QtAwesome                     1.3.1
qtconsole                     5.5.2
QtPy                          2.4.1
referencing                   0.35.1
requests                      2.32.3
rich                          13.7.1
rope                          1.13.0
rpds-py                       0.18.1
Rtree                         1.3.0
scipy                         1.10.1
setuptools                    73.0.1
six                           1.16.0
snowballstemmer               2.2.0
sortedcontainers              2.4.0
soupsieve                     2.5
Sphinx                        7.1.2
sphinxcontrib-applehelp       1.0.4
sphinxcontrib-devhelp         1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp        2.0.1
sphinxcontrib-jsmath          1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp          1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5
spyder                        5.5.5
spyder-kernels                2.5.2
stack-data                    0.6.3
sympy                         1.12.1
tabulate                      0.9.0
text-unidecode                1.3
textdistance                  4.6.2
three-merge                   0.1.1
tinycss2                      1.3.0
tomli                         2.0.1
tomlkit                       0.12.5
tornado                       6.4.1
traitlets                     5.14.3
types-python-dateutil         2.9.0.20240316
typing_extensions             4.12.2
tzdata                        2024.1
ujson                         5.10.0
urllib3                       2.2.1
watchdog                      4.0.1
wcwidth                       0.2.13
webencodings                  0.5.1
Werkzeug                      3.0.3
whatthepatch                  1.0.5
wheel                         0.43.0
yapf                          0.40.2
zipp                          3.19.2

C:\Program Files\Spyder\Python\Scripts>


Please what's your Python version?

3.8.10, sorry for not mentioning that.

Ok. That was the issue. Please look at my answer, I hope it helps.

Yes, worked like a charm. Thank you!

Glad to help. If my answer helped you, kindly accept the answer. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled. This will help users who might have this same issue in the future.

From your comment, you are using Python 3.8.10 but the stable release of pymoo i.e. pymoo 0.6.1.3 Requires: Python >=3.9.
You can either install a lower version of pymoo that supports your Python version such as pymoo 0.6.1.1 using:
pip install pymoo==0.6.1.1

Or you upgrade your Python to Python 3.9 or greater.
